# Getting error while assigning ipv6 to interface

Tags: ipv6

Hi I am trying to assigning ipv6 address like this:

```
ip -6 address add be2::176/64 eth19
Error: either "local" is duplicate, or "eth19" is a garbage.
```

Comment: And what does `ifconfig eth19` give you?

Comment: If i do using ifconbfig its going fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ip -6 address add be2::176/64 **dev** eth19